# I want to autopause the vimeo video when bootstrap modal popup and autoplay when modal closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have created a face capture modal popup box by using bootstrap modal and it's opening in the several time periods. from the background, there is a Vimeo video is playing and I want to auto-pause the video when modal pop up and auto-resume the video when modal closed. How can I do it?
This is my auto pop code of bootstrap modal

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mymodal').modal('show');


});
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#mymodal').modal('show'); // where I need to do the auto-pasue
    }, 20000);
```

I want to do the previous autopause when modal pop up in 20seconds (2000ms)